# Can one create an image grid with different sized images using css or bootstrap?

Tags: css, image, responsive

I created a grid with different sized images with the following code in CSS:

```
.wrapper{ 
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align:center;
   padding: 25px 40px;
   max-height: 190px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   min-height: 200px;

}

  .table-center{
        padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Image Classes*/

.image-box{
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 150px;
    /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 40px 30px 40px;
}
```

[My images when I resize the window to roughly 1200px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pPW4.png)

I put all my images of varying sizes into image box and everything works pretty well until I resize the browser. Can anyone offer a better solution? One will be responsive in every size?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@media` queries.  Learn about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Basically, you set different sizes for different screen resolution breakpoints:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .image-box{
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .image-box{
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 150px;
  }
}

etc...
```

Comment: Yes I am very proficient with media queries, I was hoping to avoid them as the error only occurs between 1000px and 1200px, but it does look like that may be a good option. Thanks.

Comment: Ah...  yes, unfortunately that is the only real option there

Answer (score 0):

A full jsfiddle or codepen example would be more helpful but I can say:

Try using flexbox instead:

```
.image-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more info

Comment: I was hoping to learn flex-box soon but unfortunately the code above just aligned everything on top of each other in one row.

Comment: Yea sorry I can't see your whole example or I could make it work and help you out this way. Otherwise I would go with the above answer and use media queries